# ¿Como se accede a las variables de entorno de Github desde código?

Tags: github, github-pages, environment

He montado una web en angular y la he desplegado en GitHub Pages.

Al intentar acceder a las variables de entorno de GitHub me da error, no consigo recuperarlas y claro, necesito esos datos para luego poder llamar a la API.

No encuentro nada en la documentación, ¿Alguien que me arroje algo de luz?

Lo que ahora mismo tengo es esto:

**environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    client_id: process.env.NG_APP_CLIENT_ID,
    url: process.env.NG_APP_URL,
    client_secret: process.env.NG_APP_CLIENT_SECRET,
};
```

Y la configuración de GitHub

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si revisas la captura que nos compartes, dice que esos _environment SECRETS_ sólo son accesibles [para los GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets) en el contexto de ese entorno. No para una página que esté ahí, sino para los Actions que le configures.

Answer (score 1):

Os comento como lo he solucionado. Era mucho mas sencillo de lo que pensaba.

Simplemente faltaba añadir las variables de entorno en el script de deploy

```
env:
      NG_APP_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.NG_APP_CLIENT_ID }}
      NG_APP_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.NG_APP_CLIENT_SECRET }}
```